# How to use OnKeyDown() Event instead Textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, system.drawing, onkeydown

I need to make image editor includes Text tool. Text tool can add text on the image.
I don't want to use pop-up which is inherited from Textbox for receiving text. Because the Text tool must be able to rotate 90 degree while is typing. Textbox cannot rotate.
So I use OnKeyDown() Event instead Textbox. Like these

```
 AddHandler Me.OnKeyDown, AddressOf OnTextChange
 Dim _text As New StringBuilder()
 Dim str as String = String.Empty

 Public Sub OnTextChange(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
          
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        str = _text.AppendLine().ToString
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Back AndAlso _text.Length > 0 Then
        str = _text.Remove(_text.Length - 1, 1).ToString
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        str = _text.Append(" ").ToString
    ElseIf e.KeyCode > 47 AndAlso e.KeyCode < 58 Then
        str = _text.Append(ChrW(e.KeyValue)).ToString
    ElseIf e.KeyCode >= 65 AndAlso e.KeyCode <= 90 Then
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift Then
            str = _text.Append(e.KeyCode.ToString).ToString
        Else
            str = _text.Append(e.KeyCode.ToString.ToLower).ToString
        End If
    End If       
    Me.Refresh()    '' Call Draw() function which will call Graphics.DrawString(str,...)
End Sub
```

These code can get some character such as  a-z , A-Z and number.
But it cannot get special characters and other language.

How to implement OnKeyDown() insteads Textbox perfectly?

Comment: Use `KeyPress` instead of `KeyDown`. The `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar` property will give you the exact char that you need to append. You don't even need to worry about modifiers or anything like that.